Reverse Lookup Failures in BIND DNS Configuration on Ubuntu Servers
I am currently configuring the DNS on Ubuntu servers for an assignment, and am encountering issues with reverse lookups. Below are the details from the configuration files and the results of the commands I've run:
p04ldns1.pod04.lan = master server [10.4.30.4]

Can resolve client1.pod04.lan to 10.4.30.10
Can resolve p04ldns2.pd04.lan to 10.4.30.5
Cannot resolve 10.4.30.10 to client1.pod04.lan
Cannot resolve 10.4.30.5 to p04ldns2.pd04.lan

p04ldns2.pod04.lan = slave server [10.4.30.5]

Can resolve p04ldns1.pd04.lan to 10.4.30.4
Cannot resolve client1.pod04.lan to 10.4.30.10
Cannot resolve 10.4.30.4 to p04ldns1.pd04.lan
Cannot resolve 10.4.30.10 to client1.pod04.lan

client1.pod04.lan = client [10.4.30.10]

Can ping 10.4.30.4 & 10.4.30.5
Can get out to the internet using 10.4.30.4 & 10.4.30.5 as DNS servers

Forward Lookup Zone Configuration on Master (/etc/bind/named.conf.local)
// Forward Lookup Zone
zone "pod04.lan" {
    type master; // Confirmed as master
    file "/etc/bind/db.pod04.lan"; // Correct file path
};

// Reverse Lookup Zone
zone "30.4.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master; // Confirmed as master
    file "/etc/bind/30.4.10.in-addr.arpa"; // Correct file path
};

Zone File for pod04.lan on Master (/etc/bind/db.pod04.lan)
$TTL 604800
$ORIGIN pod04.lan.
@       IN      SOA     p04ldns1.pod04.lan. admin.pod04.lan. (
                         2023100805     ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      p04ldns1.pod04.lan.
@       IN      NS      p04ldns2.pod04.lan.

p04ldns1            IN    A   10.4.30.4
p04ldns2            IN    A   10.4.30.5
client1             IN    A   10.4.30.10

Zone File for Reverse Lookup on Master (/etc/bind/30.4.10.in-addr.arpa)
$TTL 604800
$ORIGIN 30.4.10.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN       SOA      p04ldns1.pod04.lan. admin.pod04.lan. (
                          2023100805    ; Serial
                          604800        ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                          2419200       ; Expire
                          604800 )      ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      p04ldns1.pod04.lan.
@       IN      NS      p04ldns2.pod04.lan.

10      IN      PTR     client1.pod04.lan.

Slave zone file
The slave cannot resolve client1.pod04.lan to 10.4.30.10
// FORWARD LOOKUP ZONE
zone "pod04.lan" {
        type slave;
        file "/var/cache/bind/db.pod04.lan";
        masters { 10.4.30.4; }; # P04LDNS1's IP Address
};

// REVERSE LOOKUP ZONE
zone "30.4.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type slave;
        file "/var/cache/bind/30.4.10.in-addr.arpa";
        masters { 10.4.30.4; }; # P04LDNS1's IP Address
};

I have set the permissions for the reverse zone file as follows:
sudo chown bind:bind /etc/bind/30.4.10.in-addr.arpa
sudo chmod 644 /etc/bind/30.4.10.in-addr.arpa

Testing Commands and Results
Forward Lookup:
dig @10.4.30.4 client1.pod04.lan

Result: Successfully resolves to 10.4.30.10.
Reverse Lookup:
dig -x 10.4.30.10

Result: NXDOMAIN, indicating the reverse lookup is not resolving.
dig -x 10.4.30.10 @10.4.30.4

Result: Also returns NXDOMAIN.
sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Have tried  sudo systemctl restart bind9 many times on master and slave dns servers
dig @10.4.30.4 pod04.lan AXFR on SLAVE
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.4.30.4 pod04.lan AXFR
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
pod04.lan.              604800  IN      SOA     p04ldns1.pod04.lan. admin.pod04.lan. 2023100805 604800 86400 2419200 604800
pod04.lan.              604800  IN      NS      p04ldns1.pod04.lan.
pod04.lan.              604800  IN      NS      p04ldns2.pod04.lan.
client1.pod04.lan.      604800  IN      A       10.4.30.10
p04ldns1.pod04.lan.     604800  IN      A       10.4.30.4
p04ldns2.pod04.lan.     604800  IN      A       10.4.30.5
pod04.lan.              604800  IN      SOA     p04ldns1.pod04.lan. admin.pod04.lan. 2023100805 60480


First thing is to look at the error logs (syslog or systemd, depending on how you've got it set up) to see where it's objecting because you missed a semicolon

Can I ask how you know it's a semicolon issue?

I don't. The important part is to check for errors to identify why it's not serving your rDNS. In my experience it's usually something small that causes the zone to get skipped - probably not a semicolon in this instance because the configuration must be syntactically accurate
